# Is it possible to exposes a Composables Vue 3 .ts file to import in an host

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-module-federation

#modulefederation #vuejs
Is it possible to exposes a Composables Vue 3 .ts file to import in an host ?

```
name: "myMicrofront",
exposes: {
          "./myComposable": "./src/composables/myComposable.ts",
        },
```

and

I want to access a returned const from this composables to host...

```
import myComposablefrom "myMicrofront/myComposable";
```

Thank you !